# Remove "Search" text on input and only apply to one search box, not all

Tags: php, jquery, search

I am working on a site right now and have discovered that the jquery/javascript that I have implemented for the Search applies the same effect to all search boxes on the page when I click in the input field. By default, it removes the "Search" text and clears it out so that you can type your search term. I only want it to perform this function on the search box that is clicked within, not all search boxes on the page. However, if you [look at this example](http://steadfastdesignfirm.com/rgw/), you'll notice that when you click into the search field at the top of the page, it clears the text out of both. I think I could fix it with `.parent()` or something, but am a jQuery novice. Any help would be appreciated.

Also don't know quite why the border is showing up around my icon, but I'll fix that.

Here's the search function jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.search-box').textdefault({'text':'Search'});
});

(function($){
  $.fn.textdefault = function(settings){
    var Elements = this;
    var settings = $.extend({}, $.fn.textdefault.defaults, settings);
    return Elements.each(function(){
      if($(Elements).is("input")){ TextDefault( $(Elements) ); }
    });

    function TextDefault(Input){
      if (Input.val().length==0) Input.val(settings.text);
      Input.focus(function () {
        if (Input.val()==settings.text) Input.val('');
      });
      Input.blur(function () {
        if (Input.val().length==0) Input.val(settings.text);
      });
    }
  };

  $.fn.textdefault.defaults = {
    text: 'Search'
  };

})(jQuery);
```

Thanks!
Taylor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[plugin example](http://jsfiddle.net/vx3LE/1/)

here is the correction.

`Elements` contains all the  elements that are 'passed' to this plugin.

```
var Elements = this;
```

By using $(Elements) instead of $(this) in the each function, you 
used all inputs as one

```
  return Elements.each(function() {
            if ($(this).is("input")) {
                TextDefault($(this));
            }
        });
```

This line of code should be called to initialize the plugin. So it should be put somewhere outside of the plugin, in a `$(document).ready() {}` code block for example, since you need the plugin initialized for the inputs on the load of the page.

```
$('.search-box').textdefault({
        'text': 'Search'
    });
```

Comment: I'm loving the way this looks, but it's not working for me yet.

Comment: strange, it works fine on the example i put together on http://jsfiddle.net/vx3LE/1/ did you tested on your web directly, so i can see it there?

Comment: Hmmm... it's working now that I've uploaded it to the server, but it's still clearing out "Search" from all of the boxes.

Comment: http://steadfastdesignfirm.com/rgw/scripts/search.js i still see only the old one..

Comment: I just copied what you had in the jsFiddle site. Was that my old one you had on there?

Comment: You're right, I just uploaded it and it looks like I'm still having the same problem that I was having locally. No "Search" text at this moment. You're right, though, it was working perfectly fine on the jsFiddle site.

Comment: remove  this line  $(document).ready(function(){.. and its closing bracket. The plugin is declared by this starting line $(function(){...

Comment: I made that change and nothing yet.

Comment: you should avoid this practice, even though it might work. I updated my answer with explanation why

Answer (score 1):

Use a different selector.  Instead of all inputs with a class of "search-box" try giving it a unique ID or class.

```
$("#search_default").textdefault({'text':'Search'});
```

or

```
$(".search-box.defaulttext").textdefault({'text':'Search'});
```

The HTML would then be

```
<input type="text" class="search-box defaulttext" ...
```

or

```
<input type="text" id="search_default" ...
```

Comment: +1 - The plugin cycles through all elements in the selector (not just the active element). So using a different selector would do the job -- although you'll have to add the `textdefault` call for each unique selector.

Answer (score 0):

This is the method that I use, which could also be helpful for you.  It won't fire for both objects since it uses $(this) to control just the object being focused/blurred.

```
$(".search-box").live("focus", function(){
    if ( $(this).val() == $(this).attr("rel") ){
        $(this).val('');
    }
}).live("blur", function(){
    if ( $(this).val() == '' ) {
        $(this).val( $(this).attr("rel") );
    }
}).each( function(){
    $(this).attr("rel", $(this).val() );
});
```

Comment: I'm going to try implementing this real quick.

Comment: did you have any luck with a solution? :)

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use a more "jQuery" way to do this. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vf8YU/)

```
$('input').focus(function(){
    $(this).data('text', $(this).val()).val('');
});
$('input').blur(function(){
    if( $(this).val() === "" ) $(this).val( $(this).data('text') );
});
```

Comment: The problem I'm having is that some of these start with having no text in the search box, but just change the style of the input text based on focus or blur. I need it to start with "Search" in the box, remove it when clicked and then add it back when a user clicks out of the search box.

Comment: Yes, this solution puts that information where it belongs, in the html. You can include default text or not, semantically where it should be, in the content.